# SwiftUI - TabView disable background transparency

Tags: swiftui

Is there a way to disable the transparency in `TabView` for **iOS 15**? If my `List` doesn't fill the entire screen the `TabView` background is transparent, I'm looking to always show the `TabView` background.

[image]

Comment: Modify appearance of UITabBar as you like (translucency, background color, etc). This should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/63414605/12299030.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @Asperi for pointing me in the correct direction. I found `scrollEdgeAppearance` in `UITabBarAppearance`.

```swift
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
@NSCopying open var scrollEdgeAppearance: UITabBarAppearance?
```

> Describes the appearance attributes for the tabBar to use when an
> observable scroll view is scrolled to the bottom. If not set,
> standardAppearance will be used instead.

```swift
//@available(iOS 15.0, *)
//@NSCopying open var scrollEdgeAppearance: UITabBarAppearance?

let appearance: UITabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
init() {
    UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
}
```

[image]